# Annihilating polynomials of non-diagnolizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> For every *non-diagonalizable* matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{F})$, there is a polynomial $P(t)$ with coefficients over $\mathbb{F}$ and of degree $n-1$ such as $P(A)^2=0$.

Is the above statement true for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$? Or none of them?

How can I find out if this is true for any field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true iff the field is algebraically closed. For non-algebraically closed fields, any matrix (at least of size 2x2) with with an irreducible characteristic polynomial is a counterexample.